# Cin in function

Tags: c++

I created a simple structure and function for entering all the data for it. The problem is that if you use `cin` inside a function for input, then a line break is thrown into the stream.

Strangeness lies in the fact that if I put the input ID at the beginning, `cin` throws `'\n'` into the stream, but if I first enter the name, and only then the salary and iD, then there is no problem with the new line and `cin`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Worker {

        string name;
        int salary;
        int id;
};

Worker newWorker;

int setWorker () {

    cout << "\nNAME: ";
        if (!(getline(cin, newWorker.name)) || newWorker.name.size() < 1)
            return 1;
    cout << "\nID: ";
        if (!(cin >> newWorker.id) || newWorker.id < 1)
            return 1;
        cout << "\nSALARY: ";
        if (!(cin >> newWorker.salary) || newWorker.salary < 1)
            return 1;
    return 0;
  }

int main()
{
    setWorker();
    return 0;
}
```

***Output if NAME first***

> NAME: DEN
>
> ID: 1
>
> SALARY: 1
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.764 s Press any key to
>   continue.

***Output if ID first***

```
int setWorker () {

    cout << "\nID: ";
        if (!(cin >> newWorker.id) || newWorker.id < 1)
            return 1;
    cout << "\nNAME: ";
        if (!(getline(cin, newWorker.name)) || newWorker.name.size() < 1)
            return 1;
    cout << "\nSALARY: ";
        if (!(cin >> newWorker.salary) || newWorker.salary < 1)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

> ID: 5
>
> NAME:
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.067 s

Comment: I cannot get this code to work with my C compiler.

Comment: I'm so sorry, removed C tag.

Comment: you asked this question before and it was pointed out that your problem in mixing formatted input '>>' and getline